# How do I bootstrap multiple modules to display on same page with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have looked on the [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/XszIAFl9slM/Ifl98FQl-LcJ), [angularjs.org](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) as well as some serious Googling but I am not finding any clear examples or explanation for what I'm trying to do.

What I am trying to do is break my application into views using multiple modules. I know from reading online you need to manually bootstrap but I'm still not getting it write

I currently have 2 modules "thermostatApp" and "PeopleApp", and I want to attach them to their own containers shown below:

```
<div id="thermostatApp_container">
    <div data-ng-include="'modules/thermostat/thermostat.html'"/> 

  </div> 

  <div id="peopleApp_container">
    <div data-ng-include="'modules/people/people.html'"/> 

  </div>
```

what I was trying to do was to bootstrap to each container element like so:

```
angular.element($('#peopleApp_container')).ready(function() {
         angular.bootstrap($('#peopleApp_container'), ['peopleApp']);
       });

 angular.element($('#thermostatApp_container')).ready(function() {
         angular.bootstrap($('#thermostatApp_container'), ['thermostatApp']);
       });
```

This isn't working for me, I know you can attach multiple modules using an array of modules but How do you specif a element to bootstrap it to? Is it possible to do what I'm describing? If not what is the best way to approach it? I do want to keep modules as separated as possible.

Comment: So you wanted these two templates to be on the same page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel very Silly! I did't need to attach to specific elements, I just attached to the document and passed an array of modules like so:

```
angular.element(document)).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['peopleApp','thermostatApp']);
});
```

Comment: Great Q&A, jonnie. I just have 2 questions though: **1)** *Does this change the Scoping of your modules (or anything else) is any way -- namely, regarding Events?* **2)** *Were you ever able to bootstrap to specific containers? If so, did this alter Scoping in any way?*